# How to load image from an arraylist?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I can't get the `layout.xml` to show all of the images, it only shows the image that I added into the `android:src="blabla.jpg"` and all of the list use **"blabla.jpg".**

I can show the text from the arraylist perfectly fine, but the problem is only the image so i tried this code

```
public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext,ArrayList<Integer> mImageHolder,ArrayList<String> mItemHolder, ArrayList<String> mDescHolder) {
        this.mImageHolder = mImageHolder;
        this.mItemHolder = mItemHolder;
        this.mDescHolder = mDescHolder;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }
```

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewAdapter";

    private ArrayList<String> mItemHolder = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mDescHolder = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> mImageHolder = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext,ArrayList<Integer> mImageHolder,ArrayList<String> mItemHolder, ArrayList<String> mDescHolder) {
        this.mImageHolder = mImageHolder;
        this.mItemHolder = mItemHolder;
        this.mDescHolder = mDescHolder;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_list_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: called.");

        holder.itemHolder.setText(mItemHolder.get(position));

        holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked on: " + mItemHolder.get(position));

                //ini ke intent
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ListDetail.class);
                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                extras.putString("EXTRA_ITEM", mItemHolder.get(position));
                extras.putString("EXTRA_DESC", mDescHolder.get(position));
                extras.putInt("EXTRA_IMAGE", mImageHolder.get(position));
                intent.putExtras(extras);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItemHolder.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView itemHolder;
        ImageView imageHolder;
        RelativeLayout parentLayout;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageHolder = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImageItem);
            itemHolder = itemView.findViewById(R.id.NameItem);
            parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
        }
    }
}

Any help would be appreciated,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `onBindViewHolder` add:

```
 holder.imageHolder.setImageResource(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

use the setImageresource property of imageView and get the image from the list of that position inside onBindViewHolder.

holder.imageHolder.setImageResource(mImageHolder.get(position));